# Break single line to multi line as content increases inside textview

Tags: html, css

How can I break the line when content start overflowing it   , break it into two lines then three line  without using css grid   ..like we do in  *CSS GRID*  using

```
grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto);
```

then in the css we use

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

Main code which need to be improved.. without using css grid

```css
 body {
            background-color: #444;
        }

        .main-wrapper {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            border: 2px solid #222;
        }

        .oss {
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: auto;
            margin: 100px;
        }
        .btn{
            margin: 100px ;
        }
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <form name="output">
                <input name="textview" type="textview" class="oss" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <input type="button" class="bn" value="4" onclick="document.output.textview.value += '4'" />
            <input type="button" class="bn" value="5" onclick="document.output.textview.value += '5'" />
            <input type="button" class="bn" value="6" onclick="document.output.textview.value += '6'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<textarea>` instead of `<input/>`. To auto-resize `textarea` use `scrollHeight` in event `input` and use `if` to set max-height. `min-height` you can set in css for `.oss` like this

```
 .oss {
    .......
    min-height:50px;
 }
```

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

 textarea.addEventListener('input', autoResize, false);
      
function autoResize() {
  if(this.scrollHeight < 100){
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
            background-color: #444;
        }

        .main-wrapper {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            border: 2px solid #222;
        }

        .oss {
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: auto;
            margin: 100px;
            overflow:hidden;
            min-height:50px;
        }
        .btn{
            margin: 100px ;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <form name="output">
                <textarea name="textview" type="textview" class="oss" /></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <input type="button" class="bn" value="4" onclick="document.output.textview.value += '4'" />
            <input type="button" class="bn" value="5" onclick="document.output.textview.value += '5'" />
            <input type="button" class="bn" value="6" onclick="document.output.textview.value += '6'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Size of textarea does not increases as the content inside container.

Comment: I am looking for the alternative of minmax() in general..without using css grid

Comment: It still does not solves the issue i want to have it like in given video [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jOSv7fHoaZsYAgfhMsrM3eaMKwOHCGj0/view).    but instead of decreasing size in video i want it to break it into multiline

Comment: textarea is not prefered at this place as i am using it as calculator screen & it also does not solves this issue..

Comment: Textarea is the same as input (input is one-line field. Textarea is multi-line field). I updated the code and now you can set min-height and max-height, so.... I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: actually textarea is the problem i don't want to use textarea as the screen of calculator that i am developing so please suggest me any alternative ...

Comment: if you want multi-line field you have to use textarea.